# How to get more than one parameter using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem to get more parameter when I do a searching method.
This is my url ->

http://localhost:8080/sewarumah/search/searchIndex?state=1&city=2&poskod=90002&jenisRumah=Banglo0&bilangan=2

So here I want get all parameter and pass to model.

This is my controller

```
public function index($state,$searchCity,$searchPoscode,$searchJenisRumah,$searchBilangan)
{
$state=$this->input->get("state");
$data['search_result'] = $this->m_search->searchIndex($searchState,$searchCity,$searchPoscode,$searchJenisRumah,$searchBilangan);
$this->load->view('senarai-rumah', $data,$state);
}
```

And this is my model

```
 public function searchIndex($searchState,$searchCity,$searchPoscode,$searchJenisRumah,$searchBilangan){
    $sql = "select * from house_rent where houseStateId = ? and houseDistrictId = ? and housePostcode = ? and houseType = ? and housePeople = ?;";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($searchState,$searchCity,$searchPoscode,$searchJenisRumah,$searchBilangan));
  return $query->result();
  }
```

So the error show
Message: Undefined variable: state

Answer (score 0):

None of those variables are actually defined, unless you do them in the route (which seems silly). You can get them all from the `$this->input->get()` method like so:

```
public function index()
{
   $state=$this->input->get("state");
   $city=$this->input->get("city");
   $postcode=$this->input->get("postcode");
   $jenisRumah=$this->input->get("jenisRumah");
   $bilangan=$this->input->get("bilangan");
   $data['search_result'] = $this->m_search->searchIndex($state,$city,$postcode,$jenisRumah,$bilangan);
   $this->load->view('senarai-rumah', $data, $state);
}
```